# Why datepicker not working in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

My HMTL Code is like this :

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="idTourDateDetails">Tour Start Date:</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
$('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker();


var isitable = '<input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" readonly="readonly" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>';
$("#myModal").find(".input-group").html(isitable);
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/xzxrp7nn/

When I click input text to input date, datepicker is not working

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: are you using jquery.ui datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var isitable = '<input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" readonly="readonly" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>';
    $("#myModal").find(".input-group").html(isitable);
    $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker();
```

Reason, you called the datepicker before you assign via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

First : Why are you appending the input with jQuery / You can directly place it there. The issue is because the datepicker() is called before the element even existed.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xzxrp7nn/1/

like

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">

    <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" class="form-control clsDatePicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="calIconTourDateDetails" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I have removed the readonly from textbox. But you can add it .